# JavaScript Saving data from an ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Challenge:
While on URL1(random wikipedia page), make an ajax request to URL2(100 most common words wikipedia page), format a list out of the returned data to be used later.

I have to run this from the console while on "URL1"
example:

1. Navigate to URL1
2. Open Console
3. paste code
4. hit enter

So far I have been able to grab the entire html source while on URL1 with the following:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_common_words_in_English',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(response); // works as expected (returns all html)
    }
});
```

I can see in the console the entire HTML source -- I then went to URL2 to figure out how to grab and format what I needed, which I was able to do with:

```
var array = $.map($('.wikitable tr'),function(val,i){
        var obj = {};
        obj[$(val).find('td:first').text()] = $(val).find('td:last').text();
        return obj;
    });
console.log(JSON.stringify(array));
```

Now this is where my issue is -- combining the two

```
$.ajax({
url:'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_common_words_in_English',
type:'GET',
dataType:'html',
success: function(data){
    // returns correct table data from URL2 while on URL2 -- issue while running from URL1
    var array = $.map($('.wikitable tr'),function(val,i){
        var obj = {};
        obj[$(val).find('td:first').text()] = $(val).find('td:last').text();
        return obj;
        });
console.log(JSON.stringify(array));
    };
});
```

Im guessing this is due to the HTML I want to map is now a string, and my array is looking for HTML elements on the current page which it of course would not find.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question is too abstract without some sort of example data. You have `data` returning in your ajax, but then never use it.

Comment: if you just want to run your match against the HTML contained in `data`, just do `var content = $(data);` then `$('.wikitable tr', content)` if that's where your `.wikitable` is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple fix here! You're exactly right, it's not parsing the html you return, so just tell jQuery to convert it into an object it can use `$(data)` and use that to find what you need.

In essence, your 'document' now becomes `$(data)` which you will use as the source of all your queries.

```
 $.ajax({
   url: 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_common_words_in_English',
   type: 'GET',
   dataType: 'html',
   success: function(data) {
     var myVar = data;
     Names = $.map($(myVar).find('.wikitable tr'), function(el, index) {
       return $(el).find('td:last').text()
     });
     console.log(Names);
   }
 });
```

Comment: Hello acupajoe, thanks for that last one -- I however realized later on it was an incorrect way for me to be going about this.

    var Names = $('.wikitable tr').map(function() { return $(this).find('td:last').text() }).get();

This works perfectly from URL2 however [continued in next comment]

Comment: when i implement and run it from URL1 like this it errors:
    
     $.ajax({
        url: 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_common_words_in_English',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(data) { 
            var myVar = data;
              Names = $.map($(myVar).find('.wikitable tr'), function() { return $(this).find('td:last').text()}).get();
console.log(Names);
        }           
});

Comment: I noticed if I removed the .get() it returns an array with the proper amount of elements, but they are all blank, like "","","","" rather than foo, bar, baz etc

Comment: I've edited my answer to solve the issue, it's a matter of `$(this)` be sure you use `console.log()` to debug your code and be sure the variables are what your expect